# How do you integrate $\int \frac{x^3}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int \frac{x^3}{1+x^2}dx$$

what I did was,

$t = x^4$

$\displaystyle \frac{dt}{dx} = 4x^3$

$4 \displaystyle \int \frac{1}{1+\sqrt t}dt$

$4[2(\sqrt t - \ln(\sqrt t +1)]$

$8x^2 - 8\ln(x^2 +1)$

The answer given in my book is,

$\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{\ln(x^2 + 1)}{2}$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the substitution $u=x^2$.

Comment: You multiplied by $4$ instead of dividing by $4$ when you divided the integrand by $\frac{dt}{dx}$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$\frac{x^3}{1+x^2}=x-\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$ the rest is easy.
And you can write

$$\frac{x}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

apanpapan3's comment explains your error, but Piano Land's recommendation also works. Since $u=x^2\implies du = 2x dx$, your integral is $$\frac{u du}{2(1+u)}=\frac{1}{2}\int(1-\frac{1}{1+u})du=\frac{u-\ln (1+u)}{2}+C=\frac{x^2-\ln (1+x^2)}{2}+C.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int  \frac { x^{ 3 } }{ 1+x^{ 2 } } dx=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int  \frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ 1+x^{ 2 } } { d\left( { x }^{ 2 } \right)  }=\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int  \frac { { x }^{ 2 }+1-1 }{ 1+x^{ 2 } } { d\left( { x }^{ 2 } \right)  }=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( \int { d\left( { x }^{ 2 } \right) -\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int  \frac { d\left( 1+{ x }^{ 2 } \right)  }{ 1+x^{ 2 } }  }  \right) =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( { x }^{ 2 }-\ln { \left( 1+{ x }^{ 2 } \right)  }  \right) +C$$